# Restrict Picklist values without record type

Tags: picklist, global-picklist

The situation is as follows: I have a picklist on Leads derived from a global value set.

However, I don't want to show all value from the global value set.

Is it possible to achieve this without creating a record type for Leads?

Comment: What is the business reason behind trying to avoid creation of record types?

Comment: Basically because the scenario I'm describing would be the only reason to create record types. If I don't have to I want to keep it simple

Comment: So, you want to use single global value set across different objects, but display only few picklist entries from the value set (depending on the object)?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly

Comment: you're going to need either a VF page or LWC component that replaces the standard Edit page where this field is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Developing a custom component should be best possible solution for your requirement, but since you are trying to avoid record types, I'm assuming that you wouldn't prefer writing custom code.*

Restricting the display of a subset of global value set entries at object level isn't possible AFAIK, but **dependent picklists** or (*field dependencies*) can be used as a dirty workaround (***if you have a valid business case to avoid creation of record types***). For the record, I really don't like this approach since field dependencies were not really meant for this, but the approach will work.

- Create a custom field of *checkbox* type and default value as *checked*. If required, mark it's FLS as read-only for all profiles and also, as read-only in the page layouts.
- Create a custom picklist field using the global value set as its entries.
- Click `Field Dependencies` in the *Fields & Relationships* page and create a new field dependency with controlling field as the checkbox field and dependent field as the picklist field. Include only the picklist entries you need and save the changes (*or selection*).

In the sample screenshot shown below, you can see that I have a controlling checkbox field (*named as `CtrlPicklist`*) and dependent picklist field (*named as `Macaron Flavor` that uses a global value set*). Since, the default value of the controlling field was marked as checked, only the entries selected (*shown in the screenshot below*) will be displayed in the picklist field when a record is created or updated.

[image]

One major downside of this approach is that the controlling field needs to always be included in the page layout. Otherwise, the picklist field will be disabled. This isn't a good design IMO.

Also, watch out for any [picklist limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=picklist_limitations.htm&type=5) that could affect the design in long run.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like the creation of a record type would simply be the easiest solution. Correct?

Comment: Yes, and the record types can be expanded for other requirements in the long run (i.e., for other business use cases as per salesforce recommendations).